# How do I delete a breakpoint marker in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So my app is 100% done, however when I compile it in xcode the app loads up normal, but when I press the button, which is the apps main function, it encounters a thread breakpoint error and I'm not sure why.

When I run the app by itself in the simulator without xcode it runs perfect, the thread error only happens when I run it in xcode.

Thanks again for any help that can be provided!

Comment: Um...this is a scary question.  Do you know what a breakpoint is?  If not, does that mean you have not done any debugging on this app?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to xcode, I have done debugging on it, but rmaddy seems to know my exact issue and it was just that, like I thought. It was just a rather silly mistake from a newbie.

Comment: I knew it was something silly that I overlooked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on that dark blue arrow next to the "Play Sound" comment, and it will turn light blue (disabled). Or right click (or option-click) on the blue arrow and you have an option to remove the breakpoint.

Or select the breakpoint navigator ("View" - "Navigators" - "Show Breakpoint Navigator") and manage your breakpoints there.

See WWDC 2012 video [Debugging in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=412).

Answer (score 2):

Your app stops when running in the debugger because you have set a breakpoint at that line. Delete or disable the breakpoint. There is nothing wrong here and there is no error. The debugger is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 9 the easiest way to delete breakpoint is to just left-click and drag it.